# Why does IE 11 use Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8 when it's decoding?

Tags: internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

I set `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` in the head.

But when IE 11 sends API request, it will perform **Windows-1252** instead of **UTF-8**.

For example, if the URL contains `ü`, it should be `%C3%BC` in UTF-8, but IE 11 will break it into `%C3` and `%BC`, and sends as `Ã¼` according to Windows-1252.

So is there any way to solve this issue?

I tested in IE 11. This issue doesn't exist on Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to IE encoding settings, probably it’s set not to *automatic* (should use encoding defined by meta tag), but set to *windows-1252*

Please take a look here for additional details and causes:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928847/internet-explorer-uses-the-wrong-character-set-when-it-renders-an-html